# HttpMapTileDataSource.AdditionalRequestHeaders does not add to the request header

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps

I'm adding request headers with the following code example, and I'm expecting to see the information I've added in the request header.
When I follow and review the request header (Telerik Fiddler 4) I can not see the information I added.
I don't know what's wrong with the code. Can you help me?
Thank you in advance.

```
private HttpMapTileDataSource _dataSource; 
public GmHttpTileDataSourceFactory() 
{ 
   _dataSource = new 
   HttpMapTileDataSource("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{zoomlevel}/{x}/{y}.png"); 
   _dataSource.AdditionalRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en"); 
   _dataSource.AdditionalRequestHeaders.Add("Key", "Value"); 
   _dataSource.AdditionalRequestHeaders.Add("blabla", "blabla"); 
}
```

Comment: Delete cookies.  Make sure in the project bin folder the date of executable is updating.  You may be adding the headers to a different instance of the request than what you are sending.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a semi-finished code, perhaps to solve the request header problem you encountered.

```cs
public class CustomTileDataSource : CustomMapTileDataSource
{
    private string _tileUrl;
    public Dictionary<string, string> AdditionalRequestHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private Dictionary<string, string> DefaultRequestHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public CustomTileDataSource(string tileUrl)
    {
        _tileUrl = tileUrl;
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7");
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3");
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "ozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.10 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.235.5");
        BitmapRequested += BitmapRequestedHandler;
    }
    private async void BitmapRequestedHandler(CustomMapTileDataSource sender, MapTileBitmapRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

        try
        {
            using (var imgStream = await GetTileAsStreamAsync(args.X, args.Y, args.ZoomLevel))
            {
                var memStream = imgStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
                var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(memStream);

                var pixelProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTransform(), Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);

                var pixels = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();

                var width = decoder.OrientedPixelWidth;
                var height = decoder.OrientedPixelHeight;

                Parallel.For(0, height, i =>
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= width - 1; j++)
                    {
                        // Alpha channel Index (RGBA) 
                        var idx = (i * height + j) * 4 + 3;
                    }
                });

                var randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                var outputStream = randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
                var writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
                writer.WriteBytes(pixels);
                await writer.StoreAsync();
                await writer.FlushAsync();

                args.Request.PixelData = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(randomAccessStream);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        deferral.Complete();
    }

    private Task<MemoryStream> GetTileAsStreamAsync(int x, int y, int zoom)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MemoryStream>();

        var quadkey = TileXYZoomToQuadKey(x, y, zoom);

        string url;
        url = _tileUrl.Replace("{x}", x.ToString()).Replace("{y}", y.ToString()).Replace("{zoomlevel}", zoom.ToString()).Replace("{quadkey}", quadkey);

        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        foreach (var defaultHeader in DefaultRequestHeaders)
        {
            request.Headers.Add(defaultHeader.Key, defaultHeader.Value);
        }
        if (AdditionalRequestHeaders.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var addHeader in AdditionalRequestHeaders)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(addHeader.Key, addHeader.Value);
            }
        }
        request.BeginGetResponse(async a =>
        {
            var r = (HttpWebRequest)a.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)r.EndGetResponse(a);

            using (var s = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                await s.CopyToAsync(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                tcs.SetResult(ms);
            }
        }, request);

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private string TileXYZoomToQuadKey(int tileX, int tileY, int zoom)
    {
        var quadKey = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = zoom; i >= 1; i += -1)
        {
            char digit = '0';
            int mask = 1 << (i - 1);
            if ((tileX & mask) != 0)
                Strings.ChrW(Strings.AscW(digit) + 1);
            if ((tileY & mask) != 0)
            {
                Strings.ChrW(Strings.AscW(digit) + 1);
                Strings.ChrW(Strings.AscW(digit) + 1);
            }
            quadKey.Append(digit);
        }
        return quadKey.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
var dataSource = new CustomTileDataSource("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{zoomlevel}/{x}/{y}.png");
dataSource.AdditionalRequestHeaders.Add("header_name", "header_value");
// other code
var mySource = new MapTileSource(dataSource);
myMap.TileSources.Add(mySource);
```

During the test, I also encountered the problem that `HttpMapTileDataSource.AdditionalRequestHeaders` does not display. I tried to use `CustomMapTileDataSource` to derive and rewrite the related methods so that it can work normally.

The reason for saying that it is a semi-finished product is that it does not establish a good caching mechanism, and the initial loading time is very long.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I have already tried 'CustomMapTileDataSource'. 
But I want to use 'HttpMapTileDataSource' cache capability, and I need to manage the request headers.
I briefly summarize the problem.
I can't see the request headers that I added to the HttpMapTileDataSource object with the AdditionalRequestHeaders method when I follow the request.

Comment: Yes, I tested the same problem, I will report it to Microsoft, and if there is new progress, I will communicate with you. thank you for your support

Comment: I contacted microsoft about this problem.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/tr-TR/ce04280a-2df3-4716-8ba0-1e6e6d28454d/httpmaptiledatasourceadditionalrequestheaders-does-not-add-to-the-request-header?forum=bingmapswindows8

Thanks for be interested

Comment: Hi, I received a reply from a Microsoft engineer team. They still recommend that you use `CustomMapTileDataSource`. They have said that if you utilize the `HttpWebRequest` to actually get the data as part of the Custom callback, it will utilize the same underlying **WinInet** cache engine that the `HttpMapTileDataSource` is using. Thank you for waiting.

Comment: One year later, bug still exists unfortunately. I wonder if Microsoft will ever fix this. Has there been a better workaround in the meantime?